# Compilation error with Optional in generic class

Tags: java, guava, option-type

I have an unexplained compilation error with guava Optional I have this test for demonstrate :

```
package com.livingobjects.pmin.test;

import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import org.junit.Test;

public class OptionalTest {

    public class ContainOptional<T> {
        T id;
        Optional<String> label;

        public ContainOptional(T id, Optional<String> label) {
            this.id = id;
            this.label = label;
        }

        public T getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public Optional<String> getLabel() {
            return label;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetOptional() throws Exception {
        ContainOptional co = new ContainOptional<>(42, Optional.of("H2G2"));
        String label = co.getLabel().get();     // Can not compile

        Optional<String> opt = co.getLabel();   // Can
        String labelOpt = opt.get();            // compile
    }
}
```

When I try to get Optional from a container generic object I need to use intermediate variable instead of inline code.
When I use chain call of `co.getLabel().get();` the Optional.get return Object instead of String ?

EDIT: I use Guava 17.0 and Java 1.7.0_51

Comment: (Don't mind my previous comment; I misread the question.) This is not specific to Guava but seems to be a general problem with generics. It seems like if the generic parameter (`T` here) is not specified, other generic parts, even those not relying on `T`, fall back to `Object`. But even when you do just `ContainOptional<?> co = ...` it works.

Comment: Right adding `<?>` solve the problem. I find it strange that all generic are impacted ...
Thanks to you two

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
ContainOptional co = new ContainOptional<>(42, Optional.of("H2G2"));
```

`ContainOptional` should have a parameter but doesn't, so the compiler ignores all generics on that class and uses `Object` everywhere. Write:

```
ContainOptional<Integer> co = new ContainOptional<>(42, Optional.of("H2G2"));
```

and it should work. (`Integer` being the type of `42`).

Comment: +1 If you don't know the type, you can even just use `ContainOptional<?> co = ...`.